# How to display a claim in Azure B2C orchestration step in custom policy?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am building a custom user flow.

In it, the first screen the user will enter email address. On the next screen I want it to display that email address with options.

I have built the options screen and it works great, but I can't find a way to display the email claim from the previous orchestration step on the screen.

Borrowing a screenshot from Walmart as an exmaple... something like this.

There does not seem to be anything in the documents about this.

[image]

Comment: Before the technical profile to display unified page, copy the email address collected from previous step to a new read only email claim and sigInName claim. 
Modify the unified page technical profile with the copied claim and signInName as input claims (very important) and use display claims instead of output claims to display them. 

If you are looking for an option to change it like in the screenshot, you could just copy it to signInName itself and then use custom html, css and javascript to achieve the same behaviour.  

(1/2).

Comment: **Note** : Copying the email claims in input claim transformations of the unified page's techinical profile probably won't work and I cannot figure out why. 
So copy it using a separate technical profile and call it using an orchestration step.

(2/2)